# How to write a spirial function in python?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, curve

I'm trying to write a function in python that takes two arguments `(x,y)`, and returns an angle in degrees in a spiraling direction.

Suppose the center of the spiral is at location `(x0,y0)`. Then given `(0,0)`, it returns `45`. Given some other point say `(0,90)` which is the second intersection from the top on the y axis, the angle is around `170`. For any point not touching the red line, it should return an angle of what you would expect the direction to be. The spiral is just a general thing to show the direction of the angles.

Does anyone know how to write such a function?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think, you'd better ask the trigonometry part at [math](http://math.stackexchange.com) and then clarify the implementation details here.

Comment: This is The [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral)  What are `x` and `y` in your case? Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: What would the answer be if you provide a point that is not on the spiral? With floating point precision issues, it's almost impossible to exactly specify a point on the spiral (except on an axis, perhaps) so this is almost certainly going to come up in practice, even if you try to stay on the spiral.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly on the spiral. As Ive stated in the question `"For any point not touching the red line, it should return an angle of what you would expect the direction to be. The spiral is just a general thing to show the direction of the angles."`, the angle should approximate the direction of what you would expect it to be. For example the top y-axis intersection is 175 degrees and the intersection under is 170 degrees, then I guess the angle for a point in between would be 172.5 degrees.

Comment: The answers support my belief that this is a question of maths rather than of programming, so I'm voting to close on the grounds of off-topicality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an [Archimedean spiral curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html). As the page says in polar coordinates the formula of the curve is r = aθ, usually the scalar `a` is *1* i.e. r = θ. Polar to cartesian conversion is

```
x = r cos θ, y = r sin θ
```

Hence

```
x = θ cos θ, y = θ sin θ
```

Varying θ from 0 to 6π would give the curve you've. When you vary the parameter θ and get x and y values what you get would be relative to the origin (0, 0). For your case, you've to translate i.e. move the points by the x and y offset to position it accordingly. If you want a bigger version of the same curve you've to scale (before translation) i.e. multiply both x and y values by a constant scalar.

Comment: θ is a value in polar coordinates; x and y are in Cartesian coordinates. θ is the angle between the X axis and the line formed by the point to the origin. You've to convert from Cartesian to polar. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: If I do atan2(y,x) that just gives me the angle from (0,0) to (x,y)....Im not looking for that.

Comment: I added a new picture above. The (x,y) maps to some arrow on the image. The return value should be the direction of the arrow.

Comment: `atan2` to can give you values only within (−π, π], by adding 2π to negative results it can be mapped to [0, 2π); but beyind that it's a problem of polar coordinates that it has aliasing i.e. the same point has multiple representation due to angles repeating having a peroid of 2π.

Comment: You mean you need the tangent at (x, y)?

Comment: What you need is calculus. Look up finding tangents for parametric curves, there should be some simple ways of solving it.

Comment: I got it by adding pi/2 to the angle got by atan2.

Comment: I believe you ment to say that usually a=0 AND b=1, hence r=theta.

Answer (score 1):

*(I think the spiral image is more confusing than helpful...)*

for a point (x, y), you want to get back the angle theta in degrees, where (1,0) is at 0 degrees and (0, 1) is at 90 degrees.

So we want to find theta. Using trigonometry, we know that x is the adjacent side and y is the opposite side, and `tan(theta) == y/x`.

This is slightly confused by the fact that tan() repeats every 180 degrees - `tan(y/x) == tan(-y/-x)`. Luckily, Python has a built-in function, `atan2`, that compensates for that. It returns theta in radians, and we convert that to degrees, like so:

```
from math import atan2, degrees

x, y = (2, 2)
theta = degrees(atan2(y, x))   # => theta == 45.0
```

*however* atan2 returns values in -2*pi < theta <= 2*pi (-179.9... to +180 degrees); you want it in (0.. 359.9...) degrees:

```
theta = (degrees(atan2(y, x)) + 360.0) % 360.0
```

Comment: This is giving me an angle from (0,0) to (x,y) which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I added a new picture above. The (x,y) maps to some arrow on the image. The return value should be the direction of the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

You want a vector field where one of the trajectories is the Archimedean spiral.

If you take the spiral formula

> x = θ cos θ, y = θ sin θ

from the answer of legends2k and compute its tangent, you get

> vx = cos θ - θ sin θ, vy = sin θ + θ cos θ

Elimination of θ for x and y in the most straightforward way gives the general vector field

> vx = x/r-y, vy = y/r + x, where r=sqrt(x^2+y^2).

The angle of the vector field is then obtained as atan2(vy,vx).

Answer (score 0):

If someone could verify this I'd appreciate it.

This solution allows you to have a radius which grows at a different rate then the angle

radius:

```
r(t) = r_scalar * t
d(r(t))/dt = r_scaler
```

degrees:

```
a(t) = a0 + a_scalar * t
d(a(t))/dt = a_scaler
```

location:

```
x(t),y(t) = x0 + r(t)*cos(a(t)), y0 + r(t)*sin(a(t))
```

Now we can compute the direction of any t as:

```
d(x(t))/dt = r(t)*(-sin(a(t))*d(a(t))/dt) + d(r(t))/dt*cos(a(t))
d(y(t))/dt = r(t)*(cos(a(t))*d(a(t))/dt) + d(r(t))/dt*cos(a(t))
```

which simplifies:

```
d(x(t))/dt = r(t)*(-sin(a(t))*a_scaler) + r_scaler*cos(a(t))
d(y(t))/dt = r(t)*(cos(a(t))*a_scaler) + r_scaler*sin(a(t))
```

to get the a value of t for a,b such that it is closest to x(t),y(t). you can first approximate saying the distance x0,y0 to x1,y1 will satisfy r(t).

```
t0 = sqrt((x0 - x2)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2)/r_scalar
```

seeing that the closest point in the spiral will be at the same degree, adjust t minimally such that the angle is satisfied.. ie

```
t1 = t0-t2 where atan((y0 - y1)/(x0 - x2)) = (a0 + a_scalar * t0) % 2*pi - (a0 + a_scalar * t2)
```

thus

```
t2 = (((a0 + a_scalar * t0) % 2*pi) - atan((y0 - y1)/(x0 - x2)) + a0)/a_scalar
```

then the closest direction angle is `atan((d(x(t0-t2))/dt / d(y(t0-t2))/dt))`

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def fermat_spiral(dot):
    data=[]    
    d=dot*0.1
    for i in range(dot): 
        t = i / d * np.pi
        x = (1 +  t) * math.cos(t)
        y = (1 +  t) * math.sin(t)
        data.append([x,y])
    narr = np.array(data)
    f_s = np.concatenate((narr,-narr))
    return f_s

f_spiral = fermat_spiral(20000)
plt.scatter(f_spiral[len(f_spiral)//2:,0],f_spiral[len(f_spiral)//2:,1])
plt.scatter(f_spiral[:len(f_spiral)//2,0],f_spiral[:len(f_spiral)//2,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please do not just paste code, but give some context. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for how to write a good answer